# testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin - not generating code

Tags: java, maven, jooq, flyway, testcontainers

I want to use flyway to generate a migration script for a db, then use jooq to generate code based on said database, and finally use that model to deploy onto an h2 file db.

I ran `mvn clean install` and see that a db file was created.

However, when running `mvn flyway:info`, I see the migrations are pending:

```
[INFO] +-----------+---------+---------------+------+--------------+---------+----------+
| Category  | Version | Description   | Type | Installed On | State   | Undoable |
+-----------+---------+---------------+------+--------------+---------+----------+
| Versioned | 1       | create tables | SQL  |              | Pending | No       |
| Versioned | 2       | book          | SQL  |              | Pending | No       |
+-----------+---------+---------------+------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

So I then ran `mvn flyway:migrate` and see they are apparently migrated:

```
[INFO] +-----------+---------+---------------+------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| Category  | Version | Description   | Type | Installed On        | State   | Undoable |
+-----------+---------+---------------+------+---------------------+---------+----------+
| Versioned | 1       | create tables | SQL  | 2024-03-18 22:01:31 | Success | No       |
| Versioned | 2       | book          | SQL  | 2024-03-18 22:01:31 | Success | No       |
+-----------+---------+---------------+------+---------------------+---------+----------+
```

Now, however, when I try to run `mvn clean install -DskipTests`, I am still not getting my generated code. I am using "testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin" and my pom looks like this:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <flyway-maven-plugin.version>10.7.1</flyway-maven-plugin.version>
        <database.user>sa</database.user>
        <database.url>jdbc:h2:file:./testdb</database.url>
        <database.password>password</database.password>
        <jooq.version>3.18.13</jooq.version>
        <flyway.cleanDisabled>false</flyway.cleanDisabled>
        <h2.version>2.1.214</h2.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.19.1</testcontainers.version>
        <testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin.version>0.0.2</testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jooq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-jooq-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <database>
                                <type>POSTGRES</type>
                                <containerImage>postgres:15.3-alpine</containerImage>
                            </database>
                            <flyway>
                                <defaultSchema>PUBLIC</defaultSchema>
                                <createSchemas>true</createSchemas>
                                <locations>
                                    filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration
                                </locations>
                            </flyway>
                            <jooq>
                                <generator>
                                    <database>
                                        <includes>.*</includes>
                                        <excludes>flyway_schema_history</excludes>
                                        <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
                                    </database>
                                    <target>
<!--                                        <packageName>example.micronaut.jooq</packageName>-->
<!--                                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq</directory>-->
                                        <packageName>example.micronaut.jooqtest</packageName>
                                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                                    </target>
                                </generator>
                            </jooq>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/jooq</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.10.0</version>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <id>flyway-migrate</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <user>${database.user}</user>
                    <password>${database.password}</password>
                    <url>${database.url}</url>
                    <password>${database.password}</password>
                    <locations>
                        <location>classpath:db/migration</location>
                    </locations>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**Update**
What is wrong with my configuration? I have a basic script `V1__create_tables` inside `db.migrations`.

Once, the code was actually generated in the right directory, but when I reran "mvn clean install", it was cleared and since then I have been unable to reproduce it.

I feel like I'm hitting my ahead against a wall so far.

Comment: Since you've also [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78184750/521799), I'm assuming you found the answer by now?